# Python select image from pc within web-page popup

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im building a tool to fill-in form on webpage using python and one of the requirments is uploading image when i click on button it open-up this window as you can see in the image below
[image: image of the popup]

Now my question is: is there anyway to auto select image from my pc (i know the name and image path) and than double click it to start uploading ?

Note: im using python 3.7

Comment: If a pop-up explorer opens in Windows by default the keyboard input is put into the entry field "File name:" if your images or folder with the images are in the folder the homepage opens by default you can simply "fake" keyboard output with a given path to the file and press enter

Comment: do you have code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable with **pywinauto** library.

So you will need to first install pywinauto by running: *pip install pywinauto*.

Most likely you will also need win32api so install: *pip install pypiwin32*.

And from what I can see you are opening Windows dialog box with Chrome. For this to work you will need to find out process ID of service to be able to connect to a dialog box. For that you will need to install psutil: *pip install psutil*.

Code should look like this:

```
import pywinauto
import psutil

app = pywinauto.application.Application()
proc = psutil.Process(driver.service.process.pid).children()[0].pid
app.connect(process=proc)
dialog = app.top_window()
dialog.Edit.TypeKeys('"{}"'.format('INSERT IMAGE PATH HERE'))
dialog['&OpenButton'].Click()
```

Make sure you insert full path of your file instead of INSERT IMAGE PATH HERE and you are done.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 2):

if this window is opening then it might be possible you are using askopenfilename function of tkinter library available for python i.e.

example code of tkinter

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
print (root.filename) #returns file path
```

so as you can see it return a file path("root.filename") is returned after selecting the file, therefore you only have to find the function which is returning path and variable in which our path is being saved and then we have to pass the previously known path to that variable manually .

Comment: if i already have file path how do i set it in the url section

Comment: just simply write replace your image url with root.filename for example :- replace `file_address = root.filename` with `file_address = url_of_file` as in my flask project i use to take image as `file_name = 'static/images/stu_gade_rep.png'`

Answer (score 0):

To handle windows object you can use `autoit` 
However there is Python binding for `AutoItX3.dll`

You need to install `PyAutoIt` using pip.

```
pip install -U pyautoit
```

And then use below code block.

```
import autoit

def file_upload(filepath):
 autoit.win_wait_active("File Upload",5)
 if autoit.win_exists("File Upload"):
    autoit.control_send("File Upload","Edit1",filepath+"{ENTER}")


filepath="C:\\filelocation\\filename.jpg"
file_upload(filepath)
```

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Edit1 is what exactly and fileupload is that the title of popup window ?

Comment: Edit1 is the controlId of the text box of ‘file name’ and ‘file upload’ is the title of the window.If you install autoit tool on your pc and try to locate element you will come to know.